# Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-12.3.2 in any of the sources

Tags: docker, ruby-on-rails-5, docker-volume

Error when running rails docker container with volumes
bundler: failed to load command: rails (/usr/local/bundle/bin/rails)
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-12.3.2 in any of the sources

I am able to run my rails docker container without volume.
But when i attach volume as such:

```
docker run --name rails-chat-tutorial-web \
            -e DATABASE_HOST=172.17.0.1 \
            -e DATABASE_PORT=5432 \
            -e DATABASE_USERNAME=postgres \
            -e DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgres \
            -e REDIS_URL=redis://172.17.0.1:6379/1 \
            -p 3000:3000 \
            -v $(pwd):/application rails-chat-tutorial
```

I will get this error output:

```
bundler: failed to load command: rails (/usr/local/bundle/bin/rails)
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-12.3.2 in any of the sources
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `block in materialize'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `map!'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `materialize'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:170:in `specs'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:237:in `specs_for'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:226:in `requested_specs'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:108:in `block in definition_method'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
```

I have tried including these lines in my Dockerfile but still get the error:

```
RUN gem install rake -v '12.3.2'
RUN bundle install --binstubs
RUN bundle install --path vendor/bundle
RUN bundle install --local
RUN bun
```

dle install --local --path=vendor/cache

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.5.0-stretch

COPY ./Gemfile ./application/
COPY ./Gemfile.lock ./application/

WORKDIR /application

ENV BUNDLER_VERSION 2.0.1

RUN gem install bundler -v '2.0.1' 
RUN bundle install --deployment --without development test 
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential 
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - 
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs 
RUN bundle install --local --path=vendor/cache

RUN npm install yarn -g

COPY . .

ENV RAILS_ENV production 
ENV SECRET_KEY_BASE production_test_key rails c

RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile

EXPOSE 3000

CMD bundle exec rails server
```

Content of Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'devise'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.3.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'redis'
gem 'httparty', '~> 0.17.0'
gem 'rake', '12.3.2'
```

If I run the rails container with shell and gem list, i get 'rake (12.3.2, 12.3.0)'

I have been on this for the past 2 days but no progress.

Thank you in advance for those who are able to provide some guidance.

Comment: What's your content of `Gemfile`?

Comment: I have added my Gemfile @atline

Comment: Try delete `ruby '2.5.0'` in Gemfile & re-build image.

Comment: Tried it. I'm still getting the same error output. @atline

Answer (score 0):

When you add a `docker run -v $(pwd):/application` option, it hides everything in the `/application` directory in the image and replaces it with the content from your host system.  That in particular includes the `/application/vendor` directory: any `bundle` commands in your Dockerfile are completely ignored, and your host system's `./vendor` directory gets used instead.

There's not really a good answer to this, if you must have live editing and reloading in your deployed container.  The Node ecosystem is similar (third-party libraries are in `./node_modules`) and most similar questions are about Node rather than Ruby.  [Add a volume to Docker, but exclude a sub-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181032/add-a-volume-to-docker-but-exclude-a-sub-folder) suggests adding an anonymous volume for `./vendor`; *the first time only* that you run your application it will get populated from the image, but [if you later change your Gemfile it won't get updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53319877/react-js-docker-module-not-found) and [replicating this setup is unnecessarily complicated in cluster environments like Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43910919/kubernetes-volume-for-node-modules).

If you want to try the anonymous-volume path, that could look like

```
docker run --name rails-chat-tutorial-web ... \
  -v $PWD:/application -v /application/vendor \
  rails-chat-tutorial

$EDITOR Gemfile
bundle install
docker stop rails-chat-tutorial-web
docker rm -v rails-chat-tutorial-web
docker run ...
```

(`docker rm -v` will delete the anonymous volume, and it will get recreated on the next `docker run` with updated contents.  You've told Docker that directory contains important non-code data that must be preserved across runs.)

The sequence that's worked well for me is to develop my application in total ignorance of Docker: develop it locally, run it, write good rspec tests, and generally believe it works.  Only then do I `docker build` and `docker run` an image, without bind-mounting my source code into it.  If it breaks then I reproduce the issue on my local development environment, write a test for it, and fix it, then repeat the `docker build; docker run` sequence.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I'll definitely try out your suggestions. I'm quite new to docker and trying to make a multi-docker application. That's why I'm trying to set up the multi-docker environment and test on it first.

Comment: May I ask what does '$EDITOR Gemfile' means? Is it a command?

Comment: Whatever command you use to edit source files, like your application's `Gemfile`.